# AngularJs Seo dymanic meta tags not indexed

Tags: angularjs, seo, fetch, google-crawlers

I've created and angular website, and i'm trying to fetch as google in webmaster tools, site is properly rendered but in fetch tab my meta tags are

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{keywords}}"/>
<meta name="description" content="{{description}}">
```

i tryed to bind them like this, and they are chageing but google bots don't see them as such. Does anyone know how to get google bots to see actual keywords and tags?

```
app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
        $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        $rootScope.description = current.$$route.description;
        $rootScope.keywords = current.$$route.keywords;
    });
 }]);
```

Comment: *"but google bots don't see them as such"* how are you testing this?

Comment: Webmaster tools. Thats copy from fetching with google.

Comment: I wonder if maybe the fetch just isn't working the same way the crawler does. Supposedly the crawler is supposed to render the page the same way you and i see it, meaning, it would see the meta tags after they are updated. Have you used inspect element to ensure they are actually changing?

Comment: Yes they are working normally on the website, changing, updating on anchor click. But when you try to fetch them as google bot they stay the same. That bothers me for my SEO optimization

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en description is still important tho.

Comment: Yep it is, and i try to change it dynamically for better optimization.

Comment: Dunno. At this point it seems like the results you are getting are contradicting what google says it's crawler can do.